# Extracting filename and using it as label on DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a large sum of .txt files that I want to concatenate together but they are missing dates in the files themselves.

However, *the date is the filename* which I want to extract somehow and use as a label on my Pandas DataFrames - for example `Apr 2009.txt`. This would make up for the lack of the actual date in the file itself.

Is there any way to bring in all files locally, one at a time, and spit out the filenames as labels which breaks each part of the total DataFrame by date?

My pseudo code is:

```
file = 'PATH\\FileName.txt'

openfile = open(file,'r')
new_line = []

def separateState(l):
    for line in l:
        if any(x in line for x in ['New York']):     
            new_line.append(line.split())
```

Then

```
def joinWords(n):
    for listy in n:
        operation on each list (listy)
    df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
    df.to_csv('FileName.csv')
```

Where each file is a .txt when taken in are nested lists (parsed through these functions above by city).

The input looks something like:

```
[['CityName1', 'number1'.....'number2'....],.......many other lists of similar types]
```

The output I want to achieve is:

```
Date                       |    City    |   UNIT1  |   UNIT2  |.....
FileName (Apr 2009)        |  CityName1 | number01 | number11 |....
<blank til next file name> |  CityName2 | number02 | number12 |....
.
.
.
.
```

Basically I want to split each df by the FileName at the beginning of each intake.

Comment: *Is there a way*? Yes. But hard to write some code only with the information you provided and with no [mcve]

Comment: Added my functions above!

Comment: Still a little confused - can you give a (simplified) version of the output that corresponds to your input, so we can see what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: I've added the desired output. Let me know!

Comment: Are you consolidating the data into a dataframe just to save it as a csv?

Comment: Yes that's correct @BernardL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use the standard csv module in Python, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. But if you prefer to use pandas, below is a code snippet you can modify:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#get your working directory and target folder that contains all your files
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'folder')

files = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i))]

df = pd.DataFrame()

#for every file in folder, read it and append to a empty dataframe with column filename as 'Date'
for file in files:
    _df = pd.read_csv(file)
    _df['Date'] = os.path.split(file)[-1]
    df = df.append(_df)
```

The example I used above reads every file in a folder, checks if it is a valid file and stores it in list. Once we have the list of files, we just loop it and store it in _df where it appends to df with the file name. Your final df will contain all the data rows and file names.